# Am I misusing C# generics?

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, key-value

I tend to rely heavily on generics, but I'm worried I'm misusing them.

For example, I have an `Entity` that contains a dictionary of subclasses of `Component`, the type of the component being the key, the component being the value. Examples would be a `PositionComponent`, `ColorComponent`, etc.

I have methods for detaching and getting components, defined as such:

```
class Entity
{
    Dictionary<Type, Component> components;

    //...

    void DetachComponent<T>() 
        where T : Component 
    {
        components.Remove(typeof(T));
    }

    T GetComponent<T>()
        where T : Component
    {
        return (T)components[typeof(T)];
    }
}
```

The alternative I was debating using was simply making the functions use a parameter: `void DetachComponent(Type componentType)`, but I didn't like calling each method like: `entity.DetachComponent(typeof(ColorComponent));`

Is this a misuse of generics? I generally do this for container classes, since key value pairs using the types as keys makes sense to me.

Comment: This would only allow a single component of each type, wouldn't it

Comment: @RowlandShaw not quite sure what you're asking, I omitted code that adds components, since it doesn't use generics in the method.

Comment: @Shane He was simply pointing that, if you register / unregister on a per type basis, then you can't have multiple instances of the same type (else calling detach would remove one at random since you don't have any information about "which" one of this type you want removed, as you only pass the type). I'm pretty sure this is ok for you but i think that was his question

Comment: This looks like some Singleton store...

Comment: @RonanThibaudau That makes sense. Yes, there is only one type of component in each entity.

Comment: I don't think the way you have `DetachComponent` buys you anything.  You can more readably (IMHO) do `void DetachComponent(Component c) { components.Remove(c.GetType()); }`

Comment: @SlipperyPete: Could do that, but you might be introducing different behaviour at _runtime_ whereas the generic call would be for a fixed behaviour at _compile_ time. Reason being that `c` might be an unexpected subclass. (Of course, depending on Shane's usage of this `Entity` store, the use of a component's runtime type may actually be preferred or more correct behaviour.)

Comment: @SlipperyPete It's also not a drop in replace (for example, his components could be static classes, how do you suggest he pass an instance of that?)

Comment: @SlipperyPete What Ronan said, I don't necessarily want to require the instance of a component to remove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with it.

For DetachComponent, using generics is simply unnecessary -- you gain nothing from passing the type as a generic parameter instead of just passing a regular `(Type componentType)` parameter.

For GetComponent, using generics allows you to return the correct type at compile time without *the calling code* having to cast it. Here, using generics makes sense.

Since using generics

- makes sense for `GetComponent` and
- won't hurt for `DetachComponent`,

I think that for reasons of consistency it makes sense to use it for both (i.e., to do exactly what you have done).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm curious if you have any idea about a better way to store these? The whole question assumes I'm using a dictionary with keys as the type. I have implemented using an Enum of component types, but that made it feel like I was simply dividing code and making it more complex.

Comment: @Shane: If your entities can have 0-1 instances of each component, I like your solution. You don't need to duplicate your class names in enums, and your `T : Component` generic constraint conveniently ensures that only components will be passed to your `Attach`/`Get`/`Detach` methods.